# texmaker doesn't recognize \href

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, texmaker, doi, href

I need to put the DOI in the references but Texmaker doesn't recognize or work the "\href" command. I've already installed the "hyperref" package. I don't know what to do. Could someone help me, please?
Here is a PrintScreen of a reference as an example.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code building your bibliography. Copy and paste the code, we can not test code in an image ...

Comment: not going to debug an image but it looks like you have mis-matched brackets, do you intend the `]` after ACS Publications ?

Comment: note texmaker is just the editor, I would guess you get an error from bibtex? please show the error you get (`.blg` file for bibtex log)

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in the file you showed.

1. The publisher field is terminated with `]` instead of `}`
2. The inclusion of the URL should not be via `\href{...}{...}`, instead, depending on the precise bibTeX style you are using, you should either do
   `doi = {10.1021/acsenergylett.7b00137}`
   or
   `url = {https://doi.org/10.1021/acsenergylett.7b00137}`